# String substitution in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates, string-formatting

How can I implement string substitution in django's default templating engine?  I'm trying to basically implement `"hello %s" % "world"` with [stringformat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat).  I can't seem to get it right.  My best attempt so far `{{ "hello %s"|stringformat:"world" }}` gets me no output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `stringformat:E` , the `E` signifies the `conversion types` which is `Floating Point Exponential Format` in this case. Here, `"world"` is not a valid conversion type, hence it fails.

This cannot be done, as the parameter into a templatetag method has to be a `context variable`. The idea of `stringformat` is to [convert types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), and not format strings the way you are looking to do.

Comment: I'm confused because _Otherwise, values must be a tuple with exactly the number of items specified by the format string_ suggests that I can use `stringformat` to substitute values into my string.  This is why `"hello %s" % "world"` or `"hello %s" % ("world")` works as I expect.

Comment: @steaks why would you think that? The docs, as karthikr quoted, talk about *formatting*, not substitution. There is no reference to string substitution in the docs, and `stringformat` doesn't do it.

Comment: @daniel I think that because for a few reasons.  One, the docs specify _items specified by the format string_ which I interpret as the %s or similar characters in the string argument.  Second, my hello world example works.  Third, the docs give a "substitution" example.  See the _python has 002 quotes_ example.  Right now I'm thinking that the _string fomatting_ operator does support what I want.  However, the _stringformat_ tag doesn't support all of the features of the _string formatting_ operator.

Comment: There is only this much a template can do. Yes, your string formatting would work the way intended in the view, for example - but not in the django templates. If you really want that functionality, you can always write a templatetag to achieve the same

Comment: @daniel Between your and _karthikr_'s comments I understand why _stringformatter_ doesn't work the way I want.  I'll create a custom template tag.  Thanks to both of you.  You were very helpful!